# Copy Files after Publish events

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, publish

I'm trying to copy reports with a "batch script" through MSBuild. I currently have a project that is targeting v3.5 in Visual Studio 2012.

I modified my website.publishproj and added:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" >
    <Exec Command="echo @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Copying Reports @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" />
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MoteurRapports $(PublishURL)\Rapports\ /S /E /H /EXCLUDE:$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\CopyRapportExclude.txt" />
</Target>
```

But when I publish it:

```
254 files(s) copied
**Deleting existing files...**
Publishing folder /...
Publishing folder AideHTML...
```

It deletes the files I just copied. Is there a target after the deletion that I can use with the publish wizard?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to add this argument to your msbuild cmd.  That will keep it from "cleaning" any files it believes are not part of the deployment.

```
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True
```